# How do I read a postal code from a string?

Tags: php

I want to read a postal code from a string. The algorithm should see the XXXXX numbers, and also 5 numbers consecutively - like 12345, 68376, 78902, etc.

How can I do this with PHP?

Comment: Are you assuming that there will be no other 5 digit numbers in your string?

Answer (score 6):

```
preg_match('/[0-9]{5}/', $str, $zip);

echo $zip[0];
```

Comment: Really, I'm the only regex answer here?

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_match('/[^0-9][0-9]{5}[^0-9]/', $str, $zip);
```

i modified PMV's answer so that it will not match digit strings longer then 5.

Comment: What if it's not surrounded by non-number characters?

Answer (score 1):

```
$num=12345;
if(is_numeric($num) and strlen($num)==5){ do it }
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently had to extract parts of an address from a single string for a real estate website, and I found that the best option was to use google geocode API.  It allowed me to get Street, City, State, Zip, Latitude, Longitude, and more for every address entered.

I found a great guide on getting set up with google geocode API (PHP) here: http://www.andrew-kirkpatrick.com/2011/10/google-geocoding-api-with-php/

The best part, it even works with names of places.  So a search for 'UCLA' will give you all the parts of an address that you might need.

Comment: They have quite a prices scheme on that API currently. It does have a free limit but if your code makes a mistake or traffic surge you can have a 10k $ bill on your card (or more). Speaking from experience.